# Monitoring GET results (rest api) by reactivePoll or related functionalities in Shiny R

Tags: r, rest, shiny

I'm creating an application in Shiny R, whose task is to execute a process (which takes quite a long time ~3min) and monitor its progress.
The process is made available through the endpoint with which we run it. We also have a second endpoint that returns the current status of the given process.
The application via actionButton starts the process (post to the first endpoint). A process is launched that I would like to monitor while not losing the ability to use other functionalities of the application.

I used to make a similar application, but the long-term process was embedded in my application, so during it I created statuses and exported them to an external file that I monitored using reactivePoll.

Is there an option to close the result of the GET() function returning the current status in reactivePoll? I tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work (despite no error).

My second idea is a parallel process (future) that shoots endpoints every now and then and saves the result to a file that is already monitored by reactivePoll from Shiny App.

Are there other options? What do you recommend?

Comment: The question is a bit abstract, so I can't really give a detailed answer. What comes to mind first is, could you try using invalidateLater() in a reactive? E.g. pinging the process once every 1000ms to see if it's finished, and (via a if-else block) change some other stuff (like assign the results to a reactiveValue) when it signals completion. If it isn't complete, use invalidateLater to force re-evaluation at a later time.

Comment: @mkranj thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately I can monitor process because if running on external server, I have only access to REST API.

Comment: Can you modify the REST API (e.g. is it a self-created `plumber` - API?) with your own code? Then you could try to let it write the status of your first, long running task every now into a "pin" (using the `pins`-package) which you could read back with a second API-endpoint. 
Also (as you already wrote) you might want to look into the `future` / `promise` - packages that can be used very well when developing your own API (and the interactions between Shiny & API)